# Who can tell me should I use "the" in these sentences and why. Thank you

Tags: grammar, word-usage

there:

I generally understand that "the" would be used when the subject or object is mentioned again in a sentence to replace the subject or object. For example: He is an office worker. The guy goes to office every day.

Today, I write an email to my teacher telling him: I will follow your instructions in class to improve my math.  I am therefore confused whether I need to use "in **the** class" or "in class".

Another example is: We see **the**/a possible recession in (**the**) economy. I am wondering shall we need to use "the" in this sentence.

Thank you for your reply and explaination.

Comment: This is quite a broad question: "How do I use definite and indefinite articles?" A grammar should explain. But it's a tricky subject and there have been many previous questions here about them. Here is one - [What is the correct usage of definite/indefinite articles here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205099/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-definite-indefinite-articles-here) There are many more which can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The guy goes to office every day."

That should probably be, "The guy goes to the office every day". You mean he goes to some specific office. You can't generally "go to office" like you can "go to Pittsburgh" because "office" isn't a place, *an* office is a place you can go to.

In your second example, "in the class" and "in class" mean two different things. The first means in a particular class that you are talking about. The second means while you are in class generally, that is, in any class.

In your last example, you can't say "in economy" except to refer to a class of service on planes or trains. You might be able to see this more easily if you flip the sentence. You can say, "The economy is in a recession" but you can't say "Economy is in a recession".

Unfortunately, when English requires you to use "the" and when it doesn't is not subject to any simple rule. Pretty much all you can do is list out the cases and the exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question, the answer *in class* that is the synonym of *during the class.*
The second question, the answer *We see the possible recession*, which means that we know what kind of recession occures. If you say *We see a possible recession*, we don't know what kind of recession occures. You should say *in the economy* in any case. It's usual to utter "in economy class", or something so in similar expressions.